# Create relationship between two models using django class based views

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have two models Company and Campaign. I need to create a relationship between them. I think my models are fine.

*companies/model.py*

```
class Company(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "companies"

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=128, default='')
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
```

*campaigns/models.py*

```
class Campaign(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "campaigns"

    company = models.ForeignKey('companies.Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    title = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=128, default='')
    slug = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, blank=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

*campaigns/forms.py*

```
class CampaignForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = ['title','description','archived']
```

*campaigns/views.py*

```
class CampaignCreateView(SubmitBtnMixin, CreateView):
    model = Campaign
    company = None
    form_class = CampaignForm
    submit_btn = "Add Campaign"
    template_name = "form.html"
```

*campaigns/urls.py*

```
url(r'^campaign/create/$', CampaignCreateView.as_view(), name='campaign-create'),
```

My question is, when creating a new campaign, where and how do I pick up the Company pk to populate the Campaign model? What is the most secure and best practice for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but would like input on best practices still.

I added this to my CampaignCreateView

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    company = get_object_or_404(Company, id=self.kwargs.get('pk'), user_id=self.request.user.id)
    form.instance.company_id = company.id
    return super(CampaignCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

and I changed my url to:

```
url(r'^campaign/(?P<pk>\d+)/create/$', CampaignCreateView.as_view()...
```

Not sure that I like the pk in the URL since it can be jacked. This is why I am filtering on the userid at the company model to make sure that the data is coming from the owner.

I thought of doing this by registering the company in the session id but I am not convinced that sessions do not present their own problems.